# cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' and i dont understand

Tags: c#, int, boolean

I'm trying to create a brick breaker type game with a ball and bat. I'm working on making the ball reflect off the bat like it does with the walls but i the way i am trying it seems to be wrong or is something i do not understand very well:

```
private int x;
private int batx;
if (x = batx)
```

comes up with the message cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

i just started C# so i don't really understand what to do. is there another way i can make the ball reflect off the bat?

Comment: `if (x == batx)`. This is C# protecting you from one example of the silly typo-based errors C/C++ lets you make. :)

Comment: i see thank you very much. i just tried that and doing the same with y and bat y, but the ball just goes through the bat still. how do i make the ball and bat recognise each other?

Comment: @MikhelPatel A question about collision detection between balls and bats is *pretty different* from a question about comparing two integers and the equals operator's difference from the assignment operator.

Comment: @MikhelPatel: you should post a new question if you have something new to ask. Don't piggy-back, not even if the first question turned out to be something incredibly simple.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot this was something that i wanted to try to see if it would somehow help. i thought that the x coordinate and y coordiante of the bat and ball were equal and i put in that code above, i thought it would work. i guess not :/

Comment: @PeterDuniho ok will do

Answer (score 4):

ekad gave the correct answer here, but since this is an opportunity for learning:

`if` statements expect a `bool` value inside their parentheses, which is why you can have things like:

```
if (true)
```

and

```
if (false)
```

but

```
if (1)
```

doesn't make any sense.  When you do a *comparison* (`==`) like:

```
if (a == b)
```

`a` is compared to `b` for equivalence, and the statement will evaluate to either `true` or `false`.  This probably makes sense to you already.

*Assignment* (`=`), however, also evaluates to a value, and the value is the value of the left operand.  The *type* returned is the type of the left operand.

```
batx = 5;
if (x = batx) {
```

essentially evaluates to

```
if (5)
```

Which, as said before, doesn't make sense (in C#, anyway -- this does make sense in C).  The reason why I typed all that out is that it explains the compiler error you got.

*cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'*

The compiler expected to find a statement which evaluates to a `bool` inside the parentheses.  Instead, it found a statement that evaluates to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

This is where your mistake is, you use [= Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) in the condition of the [if block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

```
if (x = batx)
```

The condition (`x = batx`) should be a boolean, so you should use [== Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) instead

```
if (x == batx)
```